# How do I get Ubuntu Minimal to boot in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm attempting to install ubuntu minimal 12.10 32 bit on a virtualbox host. It freezes immediately after the screen where I select between a regular and a command line only install. How would I get ubuntu minimal to boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying 12.04 minimal, I gave ubuntu server a shot, and it gave me an error saying that PAE/NX was disabled. Apparently I had PAE/NX deselected under system -> processor. Selecting it fixed the issue. Since PAE is a prerequisite for the more modern builds of ubuntu, its essential this is selected.

[image]